# return null if no rows found oracle query with IN clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with three columns.
I query that table with IN clause.

select column1 from table1 where column1 in (1,2,3) order by column2, column3

The table1 contains only values 1 and 2 in column1. I want to return the not available value also in my result, and that should be sorted in the bottom.

example data

column1 column 2 column 3

```
1   100 11

2   101 50
```

output, the not available values should be in the last.

column1 column 2 column 3

```
1   100 11

2   101 50

3 null null
```

I tried with subquery with NVL, like select nvl((select.. in(1,2,3)),null) from dual, due to IN Clause, I am getting single row subquery returns more than one row issue, which is expected.

Also tried with the union but nothing works. Great if any help. Thanks

Comment: Use Decode function or show us your query we ll help you.

Comment: @Prathyush  I tried decode also but for the value which is not there in table is ignored. 

select col1,decode(col1, NULL,'zero', col1) from table1 where col4 = 2
and col1 in (1,2,3)

Comment: what is col1 here? is it primary key?

Comment: table 1 has col1, col2, col3, col4 and col1,col2, col3 combination is primary key in the table

Comment: Then you must try to use subquery. have something like select decode((subquery from table1),null,'test',(subquery from table1)) from table 1. I know this will make your query very slow

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with a union all:

```
select column1 from table1 where column1 in (1,2,3) order by column2, column3 
union all 
select null from table1 where column1 not in (1,2,3) order by column2, column3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't take 1,2,3 values from another table you can try with:

```
with t1 as (
  select col1,col2,col3
  from tab1
  where cod_flusso in ('1','2','3')),
t2 as (
  select '1' as col1,null,null
  from dual
  union
  select '2',null,null
  from dual
  union
  select '3',null,null
  from dual)
select t2.col1,col2,col3
from t2
left outer join t1
on t1.col1= t2.col1
```

It's better if you can store 1,2,3 values in a second table, then use left outer join.

Comment: for the union you have hardcode the values, but i will pass dynamically the  values for IN Clause. and second table is not possible. all values are in single table

Comment: you're right! For this reason I suggest to use a second table ... can you explain me the logic used to extract dynamically the values in the IN clause?